# [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys I'm in the middle of migrating a wordpress site from one host to another (BlueHost to LunarPages). I backed up everything on the old server, did a fresh WP install on the new server, imported the old files over, did the wp-config/database changes and got the site to show up.

http://www.albertineco.com

But if you navigate to any page it gives you [an error occurred while processing this directive]. I've tried deactivating my plugins and switching themes to see if that caused it with no luck. LunarPages didn't have a real idea of the cause of the problem either.

This was in the Cpanel error log:

[Fri Mar 22 10:57:32 2013] [error] [client 69.178.136.2] invalid CGI ref "/cgi-sys/fourohfour.cgi" in /home/alber27/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://albertineco.com/

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: This is definitely something on LunarPages's end. Maybe you ought to export a cPanel backup from BlueHost and upload and import that to LunarPages. It will probably cause less headaches!

Comment: From some research it sounds like some people say it's to do with Server-side includes... I guess yeah maybe a cpanel backup makes a fair bit more sense at this point!

Comment: It definitely is related to SSI.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved:

1. I asked the hosting company to provide me the FTP credentials
2. I logged in to FTP and right clicked **.htaccess** file
3. I changed the cmod for **.htaccess** file to **777**
4. I went back to my dashboard and re-did the permalink and saved.

Now, it works.

Comment: Just don't put it out on the WWW like that.  755 would be safer.

Comment: Yes, and, in general, if you get "[an error occurred while processing this directive]" when trying to run CGI from a web page, then check to make sure you have execute permission (777 or 755) on the .cgi file which you're trying to run.